# 2gp: How to debug/fix tests failing ONLY on package version creation

Tags: managed-package, failing-tests, scratch-org, 2gp

We are trying to create our first major version of new 2gp package and getting some tests failures as result of 'package version create' command.

These failures look sort of weird for us (basically post assertions just fails, like our code is not doing what it is intended to do), and we cannot figure out where can be a potential problem.

We've tried already to reproduce the same failures in the following orgs but all tests are succeeded there on a regular basis:

- scratch org without namespace with source code deployed
- scratch org with namespace with source code deployed
- we've created package version by skipping validation, installed it into test sandbox and ran tests there - still success

Is there any rational way of how to approach such tests failures instead of just playing guessing game by making some blind changes and reruning package version creation every time (it's extremely time-consuming, taking ~6 hours for one shot in our case due to huge base package)?

Can we build somehow an org to mimic config/setup of this 'shadow' scratch org used on package version creation to be able to debug tests there?

We've already used a trick with specifying unpackagedMetadata folder in our sfdx-project.json and putting there all our custom profiles - without this all tests were just failing with null pointer exceptions (again ONLY on package version create). But all other sf artifacts are packaged, so no more adjustments to make this way.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

--- UPDATE 1 ---

Providing a bit of a context and error message from our tests to give some clue re the nature of the problem we are failing.

We have a trigger on user object which tracks different cases (on create, on profile change etc.) and assigns user specific permission set when appropriate (permission sets are packaged, and no license requirement for them). So basically this assignment is not happening according to failed tests logs:

```
      "Error": [
    "Apex Test Failure: Class.XXX.YyyTest.activateUser: line 153, column 1 System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Active ZZZ user should have TTT permission set assigned: Expected: 1, Actual: 0",
    "Apex Test Failure: Class.XXX.YyyTest.updateUserProfile: line 77, column 1 System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: ZZZ user should have TTT permission set assigned: Expected: 1, Actual: 0"
  ],
```

At the same time we are trying to look wider at this problem - even if we are lucky and will figure it out somehow, next bug fix or new feature may bring us to similar trouble - that's we are interested very much in approach or clone of that 'shadow' scratch org.

Comment: Could you [edit] and add specific detail of at least one of the errors you get?

Comment: @PhilW updated - did my best.

Comment: Are you using scripting of some kind to set up your scratch org? Are you supplying a viable org definition file when you issue the `package:version:create` command?

Comment: @DavidReed We are using the same scratch org definition file in both cases, i.e. when running `package:version:create` command, and when creating scratch org for local development. The only difference is that for local setup we are running additional script to install base packages (which happens automatically in background in case of package version creation via dx command). So I would expect tests to fail in both cases, but they are failing only on package version creation (and doing that consistently, i.e. getting exact same failures after retrying couple times).